# Does a class with a constructor alone create that class if the code is compiled?

Tags: java, oop

I apologize if this is a poor question, I'm just wondering why the following code (and *only* this code) would create a `Wilderness` object? This question was on a recent exam and I got it wrong for saying `0` (reason being primarily because I don't see any line that says `new Wilderness` etc.

```
package exam1;

public class Wilderness {
    public Wilderness() { // constructor
        Region jungle;
        jungle = new Region();
        Cheetah speedy;
        speedy = new Cheetah();
        Jaguar sleek;
        sleek = new Jaguar();
        jungle.addCheetah(new Cheetah());
        sleek = new Jaguar();
        jungle.addCheetah(speedy);
        jungle.addJaguar(sleek);
    }
}
```

If I compile this code and run it, are any objects created at all? Especially a `Wilderness` object. I thought one may have to write an external class like so:

```
package exam1;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        exam1.Wilderness w = new Wilderness(); // creates object
    }
}
```

Why would I have gotten this wrong?

Comment: *"If I compile this code and run it, are any objects created at all?"* Run it **how**?

Comment: Seems like the question was poorly phrased or you misunderstood what it was asking.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 'run' as in compile it with `javac` and then 'run' with `java` in the terminal.

Comment: @bjd2385: Try compiling that with `javac` and running it with `java` and you'll find it doesn't run. The `java` tool requires the class you specify to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` (or the equivalent) method.

Comment: You are right.  You need `new` to create this kind of object.  Just having a constructor in the code doesn't cause objects to get created.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Exactly my point. So I guess nhouser was correct in their comment, i.e. this question is poorly worded.

Comment: @bjd2385: Well, you don't quote the actual question, but it sounds likely.

Comment: So ignoring the second code listing, the question is "If the Wilderness class is 'run' are any objects created?"  And the answer is "No, Widerness can't run without an entry point (public static void mian())?"  Or is there some other point?

Comment: @markspace I just think it was a poor question.

Comment: They are getting at whether you know the difference between _declaring_ a class and _instantiating_ an instance of that class.

Comment: @bjd2385: *"I just think it was a poor question."* If it was essentially the above, I'd have to agree with you, yes. A lot of that about. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just wondering why the following code (and only this code) would create a `Wilderness` object?

If by "`Wilderness` object" you mean "an instance of the `Wilderness` class," then no, it will not.

> If I compile this code and run it, are any objects created at all?

You can't "run" that code without either A) Something you're not showing, or B) A `main` method in `Wilderness` (which is just a specific example of (A)). We can't answer the question for (A). For (B), the answer is: No `Wilderness` instance is created, no; an object representing the `Wilderness` class is, yes.

Comment: On the exam the question is worded exactly as 'How many Wilderness objects are created?' but I understand this much better.

Comment: @bjd2385: The correct answer to that question would have to be "Zero." Any other answer assumes information missing from the question or an unreasonable interpretation of "`Wilderness` object." You were right, whoever asked you the question was wrong or failed to ask the question correctly (or, probably, both). :-)

Comment: I'm confused if the `Driver` class is part of the question.  If it is, then it appears to create one `Wilderness` instance (colloquially, one "object").

Comment: @markspace No, I added that; the former class `Wilderness` is the only one listed on the exam. The precise wording is 'The code sample given below is correct: it compiles without errors.' And the question states 'How many Wilderness objects are created?' and I said `0`.

Comment: OK, with Brian Goetz's comment I think I understand what's being said.  It does seam to be a clumsily worded question.

Comment: @markspace Agreed. I'm going to talk to my TA first about it then my professor. Thanks for the help everyone, I really expected to get downvoted to oblivion but this has been helpful!

Comment: @bjd2385: Yeah. I mean, by "run" you *could* stretch to thinking "they mean 'run' as in `new Wilderness`" in which case the answer depends on the definition of `Region`, `Cheetah`, and `Jaguar`, but definitely unclear...

Answer (score -1):

1 object of wilderness is created which is w .

As in driver class you are creating an object.

And 2 objects of Cheeta are created i.e. One is speedy And other one is new cheeta() in jungle.addcheeta(new cheeta());

1 object of region is created

1 jaguar is created.

Comment: The OP is correct in that we have to create that Driver class and run it before any objects mentoned in the Wilderness class are created.

Comment: Your driver class has a main function which will always run before anything.

Comment: OsamaKhalid, I suspect you may have misunderstood the question. I think the OP meant to ask, if s/he compiles and runs the `Wilderness` class *without* the `Driver` class, are any objects created at all? Not that it matters now; the other comments and the other answer do answer that question nicely already.

Comment: Okay sorry for that.. no object will be created.